# Move windows 10 banner toast notification to upper right

Tags: windows, windows-10

I got issue with windows notification banner that shown in bottom right. I already try using registry Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer with 'DisplayToastAtBottom' with value 0 but still no luck. How can i move this toast to upper.

[Windows 10 Toast Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaRZL.png)

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this cannot be achieved. You could move the taskbar to another edge of your screen instead.

Comment: The `DisplayToastAtBottom` method no longer works starting with Windows 10 build 9926 released on January 23rd 2015. You can disable notifications if you prefer.